# Apoc failed to find a compatible version

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm brand new, fresh and clean with Neo4J. Just downladed and installed the Neo4J Desktop application, working offline. Noticed that the plugins don't get the install button enabled.

Creating a graph DB and trying to install manually the apoc plugin with latest jar file (compatible one), it fails to get loaded apparently.

Using NEO4J Desktop 1.1.17 offline + server 3.5.2 + APOC 3.5.0.2 jar in plugins folder

I've followed the online doc and updated neo4j conf auhtorizing things in there.

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*
```

Restarted things but still with no success. What Am I doing wrong in here ?
Seems quite a basic issue but as there is no stupid question...

Thanks for your feedbacks
Best regards
Any hint.

Answer (score 1):

I have neo4j server (not desktop) version 3.5.4.

I downloaded apoc 3.5.0.3 which if memory serves was a zip archive. After unzipping, I copied the one jar into my plugins directory.

I modified the config file as you indicated. I used commas to separate the entries.

I **did not** update the whitelist parameter which remains commented out in my config file.

Next I restarted neo4j and the apoc procedures seem to work.

Have a look at my transcript below for the details of my setup:

```
gmc@linux-ihon:/usr/local/neo4j-community-3.5.4> ls -l plugins
total 14808
-rw-r--r-- 1 gmc users 13695353 Apr 18 09:51 apoc-3.5.0.3-all.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 gmc users  1459334 Apr 11 00:34 graph-algorithms-algo-3.5.4.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 gmc users     2217 Apr  3 18:09 README.txt

gmc@linux-ihon:/usr/local/neo4j-community-3.5.4> grep whitelist conf/neo4j.conf 
#dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*

gmc@linux-ihon:/usr/local/neo4j-community-3.5.4> grep unrestricted conf/neo4j.conf 
#dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=my.extensions.example,my.procedures.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*,algo.*

gmc@linux-ihon:~> cypher-shell --username neo4j
password: ****
Connected to Neo4j 3.5.4 at bolt://localhost:7687 as user neo4j.
Type :help for a list of available commands or :exit to exit the shell.
Note that Cypher queries must end with a semicolon.
neo4j> call apoc.help("apoc.help");
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| type        | name        | text                                                                                                                                                                              | signature                                                                                                                                                | roles | writes |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "procedure" | "apoc.help" | "Provides descriptions of available procedures. To narrow the results, supply a search string. To also search in the description text, append + to the end of the search string." | "apoc.help(proc :: STRING?) :: (type :: STRING?, name :: STRING?, text :: STRING?, signature :: STRING?, roles :: LIST? OF STRING?, writes :: BOOLEAN?)" | NULL  | NULL   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row available after 31 ms, consumed after another 1 ms
neo4j>
```

FWIW, the graph algorithms procedures also work.

It is possible that you have two installations and modified the non-running one???

Comment: @Sukay, if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and upvote it? Thanks.